# MYSQL: select part of text and cut it of based on dot location

Tags: mysql, sql, select

***If I had a table like this:***

```
--------------------------
| id |      content      |
--------------------------
| 1  | text 1500 chars   |
--------------------------
| 2  | text 300 chars    |
--------------------------
| 3  | text 501 chars    |
--------------------------
| 4  | text 500 chars    |
--------------------------
```

Is it possible to create a query which selects up to approximately 500 characters and cuts the sting at dot location.

***Example:***

Lorem Ipsum is simply ... PageMaker (here at 500 chars) Lorem Ipsum. <- cut at . location.

Is this possible? If not I will try to create PHP solution. Currently I am looking into some MYSQL functions to get this done. It would be nice if I could achieve this within a query.

Comment: what do you mean "dot location" can you change your example data to include actual example data?

Comment: Look into SUBSTRING_INDEX function

Comment: Why would you want to do that with MySQL while it can be done easily with PHP?

Comment: What should happen when there is no '.' after the first 500 characters or also when the string is shorter ?

Comment: @krtek In common writing sentences always have to end with a `.`. Most sentences are have approximately 10/15 words and 100 characters. The text inside the table is written by humans. They have to write the text in a correct grammatical way. So no . would be rare. Now I want to create a query which can select just a part of the text as a preview without just cutting it at exactly X number of characters. The last sentence has to be finished.

Comment: See my answer then, it should do what you want. You could eventually change the last `ELSE ''` to `ELSE content` if you want the entire data. Cheers !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe something like this could work :

```
SELECT
    id,
    CASE
        WHEN len <= 500 THEN content
        ELSE CASE
            WHEN idx > 0 THEN SUBSTRING(content, 1, idx)
            ELSE ''
        END
    END AS content
FROM (
  SELECT 
    id,
    content,
    LOCATE('.', content, 500) AS idx,
    LENGTH(content) AS len
  FROM data
) AS data
```

You can see it in action here : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ac4d3/2 (I use strings with length 10 for obvious reasons ;) )

Comment: It works if the text is longer than 500 characters but it will select noting if the text is smaller than 500 characters. But still this looks much like it. But I ask for minimal but I mean approximately. Sorry for that. I changed my question.

Comment: I updated the SQL code so that it returns the entire string when it is shorter than 500 characters. I think you will be able to choose what to do if there is no dot in the string (hint, it is the second `ELSE` statement)