# MySQL: grab all data that is wrapped within tag <i> ... </i> from the column

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select, unique

There is a column `mycolumn` that contains some text. As example, there are such columns:

```
NULL
hello world
hello <i>123</i> sdf <a>wonder ful</a> fsd <i>123<i>
sdf <i>456</i>
```

Probably, there is always an opened let's name it "tag" `<i>` and a closing tag `</i>`.

I need to grab all UNIQUE content between `<i>` and `</i>` from the whole row - all unique content within tag `<i>`.

As result, it should be something like:

```
123
wonder ful
456
...
```

Comment: this sounds like a poor match for SQL to do this (aside from selecting the row and manually searching for items matching the query in question)

Comment: would something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25494494/mysql-select-part-of-text-and-cut-it-of-based-on-dot-location help you? Is it MySQL or SQL?